# Specify MIME type when downloading binary file with OK() in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I download a binary file using Play for Scala like so:

```
class Test extends Controller  {

    def test = Action { request =>

        val byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/to/file.jpeg"))
        Ok(byteArray)

    }

 }
```

But I need to define the MIME file type, how to do that?

**UPDATE**

I tried with `as` and `sendFile` but in both cases Play returns a `json` format, any ideas what's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ok` (which is a `Status` defined in [`Results`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results)) has the [method `as`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results$Status) that allows to set the MIME type:

```
Ok(byteArray).as("image/jpeg")
```

Note that there is also [sendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571014/2707792) helper.

Comment: @ps0604 I've essentially just repeated an excerpt from [the official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaResults). As far as I remember, this usually "just worked" for me for "application/pdf" and images of all sorts... Are you sure that you are looking at the right header, maybe you've routed the request to a different method somehow? It could be that I forgot some important detail, though...

Comment: The server is working fine, the problem is in the browser. I'm using Angular and the request content-type is probably messed up

Comment: @ps0604 According to the "Accept" field, the "image/jpeg" seems "acceptable" mime-type though... Sorry, can't help you with Angular, unfortunately.